# Which linux git GUI client can checkout commit with a doubleclick?

Tags: software-recommendation, git

I am looking for a linux gui client which can checkout a commit with a double click. I have just tried giggle, gitk, git-cola and git-gui. None of them have that option (or at least doesn't work out of the box).

```
history | grep purge
1675  sudo apt-get purge giggle
1678  sudo apt-get purge gitk
1680  sudo apt-get purge git-cola
1686  sudo apt-get purge git-gui
```

Which one does?

Answer (score 1):

I was asking the same question and came across GitAhead which does what you want! Technically it's a right click and menu selection, not a double click, but close enough. :)

Can't speak much to the rest of the features, but it has commit checkout and diff view, which is what I needed for a live code presentation.

gitahead.com